# How to change layout to use minimum height in android programming?

Tags: android, adt

In android programming, how do you change the layout height to be the smallest it can be such that all the elements still show up on it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textinput_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textinput_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+string/cancel" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@+string/ok" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

This is my code, and when I run this, there is a lot of white space showing. This layout only shows in dialog boxes.

Thanks.

**EDIT:**

I got the height to be minimized, but the OK button is now appearing right beside the cancel button. I want it to be right aligned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using code below

```
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

you actually ensure your layout to look the way you want on every android phone on earth

For spacing, Android defines two attributes: android:layout_margin and android:padding. The android:layout_margin attribute defines spacing for the container, while android:padding defines the spacing for the view.

android:padding—Defines the spacing of the content on all four sides of the control. To define padding for each side individually, use android:paddingLeft, android:paddingRight, android:paddingTop, and android:paddingBottom.

android:paddingTop—Defines the spacing between the content and the top of the control

android:paddingBottom—Defines the spacing between the content and the bottom of the control.

android:paddingLeft—Defines the spacing between the content and the left side of the control.

android:paddingRight—Defines the spacing between the content and the right side of the control.

**Edited Code  be sure to change the name " mainactivity to whatever your  activity name has  " **

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

       <TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_username"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+string/email" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textinput_username"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_password"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@+string/password" />

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/textinput_password"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />       

    <LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/ok" />
</LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

**YOUR ANSWER  FULLY WORKING CODE BELOW**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textinput_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textinput_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="28.05" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_login"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="@+string/ok" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:text="@+string/cancel" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: specifically tell me what you want ........ you have already is used  android:layout_height="wrap_content" in your relative layout xml code

Comment: TRY ADDING ... PADDINGS IN YOUR CODE ... SEE THE EDITED ANSWER

Comment: I updated my first post. The height is now minimized, but the new issue is that the OK button is appearing right beside the close button. I want it to be right aligned.

Comment: SEE IT NOW THE  LAST XML CODE ... IVE CREATED A RELATIVE LAYOUT AND CONFIGURED THE BUTTONS THE WAY U WANT :)  GLAD I HELPED

Answer (score 0):

Add android:layout_weight="1" to both the cancel and ok buttons so they appear one next to the other on the horizontal LinearLayout.

You could also use a RelativeLayout instead, and that would grant you better control on how the buttons are laid out, you can align right, left, say which one is to the right, etc.

Answer (score -1):

Use a linearlayout and remove the margins, like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_username"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/email" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textinput_username"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textEmailAddress" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textview_password"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/password" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/textinput_password"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_exit"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/cancel" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_login"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+string/ok" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: When I tried this, I got errors, so I had to change the match_content into wrap_content, then all the input fields and textviews and buttons are all overlapping each other.

Comment: actually I added the orientation to be horizontal and that helped. But now the OK button is appearing right beside the cancel button. I want the OK button to be right aligned. I updated my first post with new code.